# does anyone have an imac compatible with ubuntu?

Tags: powerpc, cd-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to install ubuntu on imac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162302/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-imac)

sorry for bad english

as i have posted before. i'am trying to install an ubuntu. any flavor or version would do. i really want to try it. my imac was corrupted. i have download a **ubuntu 10.04 and xubuntu** 10.10 but when i am trying to install it.. i couldn't pass through the partitioning part. could someone give me an advise.

and if so what version is compatible with an imac g5, 17 inch